# Leitura de apenas números inteiros em c

Tags: c

Eu sou novo em programação e estou tendo um problema, fiz um código que lê três números inteiros.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main () {
int i,v[3];
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
        printf("Numero:");
        scanf("%d",&v[i]);
}
for (i = 0;  i < 3; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",v[i]);
}
}
```

Entretanto, quando é digitado um numero decimal, ele não funciona como deveria.
Por exemplo, coloquei 2.5 como entrada e o programa apenas deixou eu fazer isso e gerou isto abaixo:

```
 Numero:2.5
 Numero:Numero:2 
 0
 1
```

Também fiz outro código para ver se dava certo mas ainda o mesmo problema

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
int k = 0,i,v[3],valor;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   do
    {   
        printf("Numero:");
        scanf("%d",&v[i]);
        valor = v[i] - int(v[i]);
        if (valor == 0) k = 1;
        else printf ("Digite apenas inteiros\n");
    }while(k != 1);
}
for (i = 0;  i < 3; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",v[i]);
}
```

}

Comment: E o que era suposto acontecer caso um decimal fosse digitado?

Comment: Se está a definir como `int` então so pode colocar numeros inteiros, se quer com casas decimais então é `float`

Comment: As entradas fornecidas tem que ser compatíveis com o que está especificado na instrução de leitura. Caso sua entrada possa ser qualquer coisa e você queira selecionar partes dela então leia como uma string de caracteres e depois faça o tratamento adequado da string lida.

Answer (score 2):

Troque o int por float, int é para numero inteiros (1/2/3), float representa números fracionários e números reais (o que inclui os números inteiros).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main () {
float v[3];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    printf("Numero:");
    scanf("%f",&v[i]);
}
for (i = 0;  i < 3; i++)
{
    printf("%.1f\n",v[i]);
    //coloca o print apenas com 1 casa decimal, editar conforme o pedido do projeto.
}
return 0;
}
```

Refiz aqui e funcionou perfeitamente.